# How to move the cursor to the end of the URL

Tags: iphone, ios

When I am on a webpage in iOS Safari, what's the fastest/easiest way to add text to the end of the URL?

Tapping the URL selects the whole thing, shows only the start. I can force touch and move the cursor manually from the start to the end, it takes aeons. I can similarly drag the selection-start handle to the end, takes a long time too. Both these methods are finnicky as well the cursor may not end up where I want on the first try.